# How to change a value inside a list which is a value for a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I try to change one value inside the list but all values change for all keys.

```
vertex_list = ['a','b']
distance_dict = dict.fromkeys(vertex_list, [10, 'None'])
distance_dict['a'][0] = 1
print(distance_dict)
```

output:

```
{'a': [1, 'None'], 'b': [1, 'None']}
```

when I built the dictionary with traditional { } it works fine. I guess the problem is for the list inside **dict.fromkeys**, which creates one list for all dictionary keys. is there a solution to fix it. without using ''for'' and { } to build the dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault),

> `fromkeys()` is a class method that returns a new dictionary. value
> defaults to `None`. All of the values refer to just a single instance,
> **so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object
> such as an empty list**. To get distinct values, use a **dict
> comprehension** instead.

Means that `dict.fromkeys` is useful if the second argument is a singleton instance(like `None`). So the solution is to use the dict comprehension.

```
distance_dict = {vertex: [10, None] for vertex in vertex_list}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print the id of distance_dict 's value created by `dict.fromkeys`:

```
vertex_list = ['a','b']
distance_dict = dict.fromkeys(vertex_list, [10, 'None'])

print(id(distance_dict['a']), id(distance_dict['b']))
print(id(distance_dict['a']) == id(distance_dict['b']))
```

Output:

```
2384426495040 2384426495040
True
```

`distance_dict['a']` and `distance_dict['b']` are actually the same `list` object, occupying the same memory space.

If you use the dict comprehension:

```
distance_dict = {vertex: [10, None] for vertex in vertex_list}
print(id(distance_dict['a']) == id(distance_dict['b']))
```

Output:

```
False
```

They are different list objects with the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve with:

```
vertex_list = ['a','b']
distance_dict =  {x: [10, 'None'] for x in vertex_list}
distance_dict['a'][0] = 1
print(distance_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 'None'], 'b': [10, 'None']}
```